# is there any sites hosting for .net

Tags: asp.net, hosting

there is a hosting for javascript and jquery programs such as jsfiddle. but i dont know is there any .net hosting site to post project to some one through the web as we do in the jsfiddle. if so please tell me..
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a place I can run C# code online?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871958/is-there-a-place-i-can-run-c-code-online)

Comment: See the other question it has link to what you're after (http://www.coderun.com/ide/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can find a site where you can host ad hoc pieces of code like you can on jsfiddle - as you know, C# code has to be compiled before it will execute...

But I've found LINQPad (http://www.linqpad.net) to be excellent for running snippets of code *locally*. If you need to share code, you could email it to your friends/colleagues and they can paste into LINQPad and run them as standalone pieces of code without the need for Visual Studio and the `csc` compiler.

HTH.

EDIT: Correction: [Coderun](http://www.coderun.com) is what you need. Its blown me away!

Comment: He is talking about IIS hosting.

Comment: I'm not sure that he is - I think he wants something like JSFiddle for c# - ie. a place you can post smallish bits of code that others can see and/or work on.

Comment: @5arx..it is only for c# and not supported to database operations..right! any way great thing thank you

Comment: Sorry, confused because you didn't tag your question with `c#`

Still, its a great piece of software engineering and well worth at least a quick look. Perhaps you could write a version for VB.Net - would make a great project ;-)

BTW, LINQPad is great for database ops and LINQ (you'd never guess from the name, would you?!).

Comment: @5arx..but linqpad is downloadable version right..! how we can share to others that one..?

Comment: Yes it is. its not _exactly_ what you're looking for, but it is freely downloadable so you could get your friends/colleagues to download it and share code snippets via social networking/email/ftp etc.?